# Customizing Django Admin Search

Tags: django, customization, admin

I want to customize my Django Admin Search form.
Like this picture, I want to add select box to choose search fields.
Is there any built in parameter in Django? or Is there other way to make this possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YPLm.png)

Comment: You have to override the `admin/search_form.html` manually

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add search_fields to your model admin class, like below:

```
# admin.py

class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
...
search_fields = (
    'field1',
    'field2',
    'field3',
)
```

This way the search will only apply to these fields of your model.